# How to sumif based on time and group excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

How can I calculate the total for a particular item, date wise? For example, we have :

```
Date    item    qty

3-Mar-21    blue    1

3-Mar-21    green    0

3-Mar-21    green    2

3-Mar-21    blue    2

3-Mar-21    red    1

4-Mar-21    red    1

4-Mar-21    blue    2

4-Mar-21    green    4

4-Mar-21    green    2

4-Mar-21    red    3

4-Mar-21    blue    1
```

Such that the results will be:

```
3-Mar-21 blue 3

3-Mar-21 green 2

3-Mar-21 red 1

4-Mar-21 blue 3

4-Mar-21 green 6

4-Mar-21 red 4
```

Is there a quick way to do this excel?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a pivot table

Comment: I've done the pivot table, but how can this table go back into the format the original data used to be? @Stefan

Comment: You can also use a sumifs() . But it will require some steps to get all the unique dates and colors .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the table columns A and B to a new position.
In my example I will use E1 as the position.

Remove duplicates under data in Excel ribbon on the new table.

In G2 add this formula:

```
= SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,E2,B:B,F2)
```

And fill down the formula to where it ends.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 3 columns:

1. The Date
2. The Color
3. The Number

Then you sort columns 1. and 2. The remaining problem: You must write a VBA-Macro to add the numbers.